# Update a value in a getx controller before it has been rendered

Tags: flutter-getx

I have a long list of items (objects) and each item has a getx controller.
`Get.put(ItemController(itemModel), tag: itemModel.value.id.toString())` is set in the `ListView.builder()` when the item tile is created, but it seems that the controller only actually gets created when the tile is *displayed* and only the first 10 or so are displayed initially.

I then need to update the values for all (many) of the items.

When I attempt to update the values in the item controllers, it can't "find" the controllers (because they have not yet been created).

Is it ok to use `Get.put()` again for the same item?  Or is there a better way to access these item controllers?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a method which loops through your list item and `put`s your dependencies for each item.
And you need to call that method on the `build` method, before `ListView.builder`.

- GetX only creates the dependencies when they are needed. Like, if you just 'Get.put(Something())', it will not necessarily be called at the moment of calling `Get.put`. Usually the dependencies gets created when that dependency is being used for the first time. So GetX will create `Something` when `something.someOtherThing` is called.